# How to get typed object from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a nodejs application in typescript, and I recently started using mongoose for querying the mongo db, but I am struggling to find a way to get the typed object from the findById method. Is there a way to get the typed object from that method by some means?

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
export const LinksCacheSchema = new Schema({
    ts: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    imdbId: String,
    parentLink: String,
    playableLink: String,
    status: String,
    title: String,
    size: Number,
    contentType: String,
}, { collection: 'links_cache' });

export const LinksCacheList = mongoose.model('LinksCache', LinksCacheSchema);


const linkInfo = await LinksCacheList.findById(documentId); //this is the one returning type of any instead of LinksCacheSchema or any specific type
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create and export and Interface for that schema:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, Model } from 'mongoose';

export interface ILinksCacheSchema extends Document {
    ts: Date,
    imdbId: string,
    parentLink: string,
    playableLink: string,
    status: string,
    title: string,
    size: number,
    contentType: string,
}

const LinksCacheSchema = new Schema({
    ts: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    imdbId: String,
    parentLink: String,
    playableLink: String,
    status: String,
    title: String,
    size: Number,
    contentType: String,
}, { collection: 'links_cache' });

export const LinksCacheList: Model<ILinksCacheSchema> = mongoose.model('LinksCache', LinksCacheSchema);

// in your app logic
const linkInfo = await LinksCacheList.findById(documentId);
```

Creating the schema twice can become a little tedious so I suggest that you take a look at this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mongoose